# What are some Wikipedia articles on statistics that contain erroneous statements?

Tags: references, teaching

I've noticed that sometimes, statements made in Wikipedia articles about statistics are criticized on CrossValidated.

I understand that one does not necessarily have the time to edit an article to fix directly a given issue with it (e.g. it could require to rewrite completely an article). But I think it might be a good idea to have a sort of inventory of these problems (with a brief summary), so someone else can look into it more closely and maybe correct these articles when they have the time.

It might also serve as a warning to readers, to double-check information about statistics available on Wikipedia (which should be common sense, but unfortunately isn't always).

I'm not sure if my question is OK relative to the editorial policy of CrossValidated, so feel free to close it if it isn't relevant.

Thanks,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (a) it asks for a list of answers (any of which might be a matter of opinion) and (b) it focuses on a matter that will change quickly over time.  Both make it unsuitable for this site (or any SE site).  The right way to address apparent problems on Wikipedia is through its own editing process.

Comment: @whuber: OK, I understand. Thanks for  taking the time to explain.

Comment: @Coris Welcome to CV. Great question, I sympathize, just a pity it is off-topic. Wikipedia often does not cover statistics well. Many have the warning "This article has multiple issues ...", and usually for good reason. For example, the  confidence interval entry has a major error that's been there at least 10 years. I giess I will get around to it eventually